# Latency problem on the serial link of an ARM embedded system

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-serialport

**SerialPort Version**

9.0.7

**Node Version**

14.15.0

**Platform**

Linux BUILDROOT 4.9.88 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 11 00:27:43 CEST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

**Architecture**

ARM

**Hardware or chipset of serialport**

i.MX6

**What steps will reproduce the bug?**

GPS Data Source: The GPS data frames are sent via a reliable software, NemaStudio. Use burst mode
[Nema Studio screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isExv.png)

GPS Data Example:

```
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,<UTC>
$GPTEST,1,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,2,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,3,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,4,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,5,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,6,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,7,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,8,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,9,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,10,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
$GPTEST,11,<UTC>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Code example:

```
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyS0', { baudRate: 4800 });

let startTime = Date.now();
port.on('data', (data) => {
  const endTime = Date.now();
  const elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
  console.log(data.toString())
  console.log(elapsedTime + " ms")
  startTime = endTime
});
```

My logs :

```
$GPTEST,9,093439.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,10,093439.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*08
$GPTEST,11,093439.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*09
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093440.97*32
$GPTEST,1,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,2,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,3,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,4,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,5,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,6,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,7,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,8,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,9,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,10,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*06
$GPTEST,11,093440.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*07
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093441.97*33
$GPTEST,1,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,2,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,3,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,4,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,5,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,6,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,7,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,8,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,9,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,10,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*07
$GPTEST,11,093441.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*06
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093442.97*30
$GPTEST,1,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,2,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,3,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,4,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,5,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,6,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,7,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,8,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,9,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,10,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*04
$GPTEST,11,093442.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*05
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093443.97*31
$GPTEST,1,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,2,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,3,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,4,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,5,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,6,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,7,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,8,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,9,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,10,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*05
$GPTEST,11,093443.97,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*04
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093444.99*38
$GPTEST,1,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,2,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,3,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,4,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,5,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,6,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,7,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,8,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,9,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,10,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0C
$GPTEST,11,093444.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0D
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093445.99*39
$GPTEST,1,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,2,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,3,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,4,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,5,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,6,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,7,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,8,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,9,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,10,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0D
$GPTEST,11,093445.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0C
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093447.00*3B
$GPTEST,1,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,2,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,3,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,4,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,5,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,6,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,7,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,8,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,9,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,10,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPTEST,11,093447.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032
8550 ms
.
340 ms
1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093447.99*3B
$GPTEST,1,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,2,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,3,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,4,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,5,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,6,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,7,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,8,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,9,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,10,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPTEST,11,093447.99,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093449.00*35
$GPTEST,1,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,2,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,3,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,4,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,5,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,6,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,7,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,8,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,9,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,10,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*01
$GPTEST,11,093449.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093449.98*34
$GPTEST,1,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,2,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,3,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,4,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,5,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,6,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,7,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,8,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,9,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,10,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
$GPTEST,11,093449.98,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*01
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093451.00*3C
$GPTEST,1,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,2,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,3,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,4,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,5,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,6,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,7,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,8,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,9,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,10,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*08
$GPTEST,11,093451.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*09
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093452.00*3F
$GPTEST,1,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,2,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,3,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,4,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,5,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,6,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,7,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,8,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,9,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,10,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0B
$GPTEST,11,093452.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0A
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093453.02*3C
$GPTEST,1,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,2,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,3,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,4,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,5,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,6,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,7,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,8,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,9,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,10,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*08
$GPTEST,11,093453.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*09
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093454.02*3B
$GPTEST,1,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,2,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,3,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,4,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,5,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,6,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,7,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,8,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,9,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,10,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPTEST,11,093454.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093455.03*3B
$GPTEST,1,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,2,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,3,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,4,0934
8180 ms
5
340 ms
5.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,5,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,6,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,7,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,8,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,9,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,10,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPTEST,11,093455.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093456.01*3A
$GPTEST,1,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,2,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,3,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,4,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,5,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,6,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,7,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,8,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,9,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,10,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPTEST,11,093456.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093457.03*39
$GPTEST,1,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,2,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,3,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,4,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,5,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,6,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,7,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,8,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,9,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,10,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0D
$GPTEST,11,093457.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0C
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093458.02*37
$GPTEST,1,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,2,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,3,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,4,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,5,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,6,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,7,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,8,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,9,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,10,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*03
$GPTEST,11,093458.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*02
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093459.02*36
$GPTEST,1,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,2,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,3,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,4,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,5,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,6,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,7,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,8,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,9,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,10,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*02
$GPTEST,11,093459.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*03
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093500.02*3B
$GPTEST,1,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,2,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,3,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,4,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,5,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,6,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,7,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,8,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,9,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,10,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPTEST,11,093500.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093501.02*3A
$GPTEST,1,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,2,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,3,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,4,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,5,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,6,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,7,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,8,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,9,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,10,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0E
$GPTEST,11,093501.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0F
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093502.03*38
$GPTEST,1,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,2,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,3,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,4,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,5,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,6,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,7,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,8,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8190 ms
,
340 ms
,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,9,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,10,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0C
$GPTEST,11,093502.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0D
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093503.02*38
$GPTEST,1,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,2,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,3,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,4,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,5,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,6,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,7,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,8,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,9,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,10,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0C
$GPTEST,11,093503.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0D
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093504.02*3F
$GPTEST,1,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,2,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,3,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,4,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,5,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,6,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,7,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,8,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,9,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,10,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0B
$GPTEST,11,093504.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0A
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093505.02*3E
$GPTEST,1,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,2,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,3,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,4,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,5,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,6,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,7,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,8,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,9,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,10,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0A
$GPTEST,11,093505.02,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0B
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093506.03*3C
$GPTEST,1,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,2,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,3,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,4,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,5,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,6,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,7,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,8,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,9,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,10,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*08
$GPTEST,11,093506.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*09
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093507.01*3F
$GPTEST,1,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,2,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,3,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,4,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,5,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,6,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,7,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,8,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,9,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,10,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0B
$GPTEST,11,093507.01,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*0A
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093508.03*32
$GPTEST,1,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,2,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,3,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,4,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,5,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,6,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,7,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*30
$GPTEST,8,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F
$GPTEST,9,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,10,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*06
$GPTEST,11,093508.03,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*07
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.003,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093509.05*35
$GPTEST,1,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*31
$GPTEST,2,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*32
$GPTEST,3,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*33
$GPTEST,4,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*34
$GPTEST,5,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*35
$GPTEST,6,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*36
$GPTEST,7,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*37
$GPTEST,8,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*38
$GPTEST,9,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,10,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*01
$GPTEST,11,093509.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
$GPRMC,123435.00,A,5725.8902,N,01032.1345,E,0.00
8190 ms
3
340 ms
,0.0,260224,4.4,E,D,093510.05*3D
$GPTEST,1,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*39
$GPTEST,2,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3A
$GPTEST,3,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3B
$GPTEST,4,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3C
$GPTEST,5,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3D
$GPTEST,6,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3E
$GPTEST,7,093510.05,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*3F

430 ms
```

**What happens?**

I am experiencing a significant latency issue while retrieving GPS data via a serial connection using the "serialport" Node.js dependency on an ARM embedded system. The latency manifests as an initial 8-second delay, followed by the reception of multiple frames that should have been received during that period. This pattern repeats with subsequent delays.

When utilizing the port.on("data") or parser.on("data") events, there are noticeable delays in processing GPS data. This latency impacts the responsiveness of my application and the accuracy of the received data.

**What should have happened?**

Data should be emitted faster, for example when the buffer defined with "highWaterMark" is full.
How to reduce this latency of almost 8 seconds ?

**Additional information**

Steps Tried:

- Change setting "highWaterMark" to increase or reduce the buffer size
- Don't use the parser like in the code example
- Use port.read() with while loop or setTimeout

**Important note: I must keep the baudrate at 4800**

My original post on node-serialport github : https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/issues/2754